# Manipulating column text in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited text file like this-

> test.txt

```
chrom1  start1  end1
    2   8828280 8828281
    2   8828952 8828953
    2   115627275   115627276
    3   63945545    63945546
    3   109753479   109753480
    3   109753640   109753641
    4   31116488    31116489
    4   31116523    31116524
```

How can I do the following tasks in a unix shell-

1. change the column name "chrom1" to "chr" and
2. add "chr" in front of the each values in column "chr".

The output should look like -

```
 chr    start1  end1
 chr2   8828280 8828281
 chr2   8828952 8828953
 chr2   115627275   115627276
 chr3   63945545    63945546
 chr3   109753479   109753480
 chr3   109753640   109753641
 chr4   31116488    31116489
 chr4   31116523    31116524
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$1 = "chr" (NR==1 ? "" : $1)} 1' file

chr   start1     end1
chr2  8828280    8828281
chr2  8828952    8828953
chr2  115627275  115627276
chr3  63945545   63945546
chr3  109753479  109753480
chr3  109753640  109753641
chr4  31116488   31116489
chr4  31116523   31116524
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. If I want to do the same two changes also on column 4 of the same file, could you suggest how to do that?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand as your question only mentions first column.

Comment: If the changes have to be made on column 4 instead of column 1.

Comment: Just change `$1` to `$4` as `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$4 = "chr" (NR==1 ? "" : $4)} 1' file`

Comment: I think OFS="\t" is enough otherwise first column does not look alright.